# Delete specific word from .txt file C#

Tags: c#, file

So I've been working on a Console inventory system that would have options to add/remove things and save it in a .txt file. I've managed to add things to a .txt file and save it, but I am unable to delete specific words from .txt file. The code that I've attached below is supposed to remove the word that was saved in the string from the text file that I've opened up. But after running the code and checking if it's there or not, I found out that it is still there. I am new to C# so I haven't got much knowledge about this so any help would be appreciated!

```
static void RemoveStock()
{
    Console.WriteLine("==============================");
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\Ibrah\OneDrive\Desktop\SDAM\Stock Management\Stock Management System\Intentory System\database\Stock.txt.txt";
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the item code you'd like to remove: ");
    string itemCode = Console.ReadLine();
    lines.Remove(itemCode);
    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);

}
```

Also, after fixing the above. What I forgot to mention was that for example, when I add to my inventory (text file) item code AP01 with a quantity of 100. It'll have the following in my text file:

```
AP01 100
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is that after I put in my itemCode for removing the item from the text file, I'm trying to ask the user for an input of 'quantity'. So for example if I put itemCode as AP01 (to remove), it will then ask me to input a value, for example 25.

So this

```
AP01 100
```

would become this

```
AP01 75
```

here's my updated code after I got my answer:

```
    Console.WriteLine("==============================");
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\Ibrah\OneDrive\Desktop\SDAM\Stock Management\Stock Management System\Intentory System\database\Stock.txt.txt";
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the item code you'd like to remove: ");
    string itemCode = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount that you'd like to remove: ");
    string itemQuantity = Console.ReadLine();

    var newLines = lines.Where(line => !line.Contains(itemCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, newLines);
```

Comment: Just a side note - when reading and writing to the same file it is advisable to write to a temporary file, then, when successfully saved, delete the original file and rename the temporary to the original. This ensures you always has a full copy of your file on disk at all times. Imagine if the code had an error halfway through writing over the original file - you'd lose everything then.

Comment: Understood, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `List<T>.Remove()` will only remove the entry from the list, and not necessarily the word. This is under the assumption that the text file has more than the item code in the line. Assuming the text file looked something like this:

> Hello world
>
> Yes, what a lovely day it is to say hello
>
> Good day

Than you can write the following code to remove 'Hello':

```
string filePath = @"path\to\file.txt";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
string itemCode = "Hello";
// If you don't want the replace to be case insensitive, do line.Replace(itemCode, string.Empty)
var newLines = lines.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, itemCode, string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, newLines);
```

Output would be:

> world
>
> Yes, what a lovely day it is to say
>
> Good day

If you're wanting to remove the line that has your item code, replace the `newLine` with:

```
var newLines = lines.Where(line => !line.Contains(itemCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Which the output would be

> Good day

**Edit**

Based on your edit, you'll likely want to create a model to represent the items in your text file, like so:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(string input)
    {
        var splitInput = input.Split(' ');
        Code = splitInput[0];
        Qty = int.Parse(splitInput[1]);
    }

    public Item(string code, int qty)
    {
        Code = code;
        Qty = qty;
    }

    public string Code { get; }
    public int Qty { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Code} {Qty}";
    }
}
```

And the code would look something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        
    string filePath = @"path\to\file.txt";
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Select(line => new Item(line));

    string itemCode = "AP01";
    int qty = 25;

    var newLines = lines
        .Select(item => item.Code == itemCode ? new Item(item.Code, item.Qty - qty) : item)
        .Where(item => item.Qty > 0)
        .Select(item => item.ToString());

    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, newLines);
}
```

This will reduce the qty down, and if they're 0 or less, remove them from the text file.

Comment: Hey mate,first of all thank you very much! it worked :) Now also, what If for example, my text file has "Apple" and next to it is the quantity "100", and after asking for the itemCode, I ask for how much they want to remove, is it possible to deduct the quantity from 100?

Comment: @Ibby1501 Are you able to edit your question with an example of the text file, and what you're wanting to achieve?

Comment: Hey @hayden, I've edited it now, please have a look and any help would be appreciated. Also, thanks a lot for the previous answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much :) Much appreciated! it all makes sense now. Thanks once again!